# ruby-snmp: how to automatically convert response to its proper type?

Tags: ruby, snmp

In ruby I read some SNMP registers. Response is an array of objects.

Is there a nice way to convert each object to the proper type avoiding the `case..when` in the following code? It looks strange that it must be converted  manually as the type is already known:

```rb
require 'snmp'

HOST = '127.0.0.1'.freeze

registers = ['sysContact.0', 'sysUpTime.0',
             'upsIdentManufacturer.0', 'upsIdentModel.0', 'upsIdentName.0']

params_array = {}
SNMP::Manager.open(host: HOST) do |manager|
  manager.load_module('UPS-MIB')
  response = manager.get(registers)
  response.each_varbind do |vb|

    ##################################
    # change from here...

    value = nil
    case vb.value.asn1_type
    when 'OCTET STRING'        # <==========
      value = vb.value        
    when 'INTEGER'             # <==========
      value = vb.value.to_i
    when 'TimeTicks'           # <==========
      value = vb.value.to_s
    else
      puts "Type '#{vb.value.asn1_type}' not recognized!"
      exit(1)
    end
    params_array[vb.name.to_s] = value

    # ... to here
    ##################################

    # with something like
    # params_array[vb.name.to_s] = vb.value._to_its_proper_type_

  end
end
pp params_array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code in the [gem repo](https://github.com/hallidave/ruby-snmp/blob/4b9deda96f14f5a216e9743313cf100f9ed1da45/lib/snmp/varbind.rb), it doesn't look like like there is a method for this.  I suppose you could try to monkey patch it, but not sure if it's worth the trouble.

If you don't like the switch syntax, you could just use a hash lookup like this:

```
require 'snmp'

HOST = '127.0.0.1'.freeze

TYPE_VALUES = {
  'OCTET STRING' => :to_s,
  'INTEGER' => :to_i,
  'TimeTicks' => :to_s
}.freeze

registers = ['sysContact.0', 'sysUpTime.0',
             'upsIdentManufacturer.0', 'upsIdentModel.0', 'upsIdentName.0']

params_array = {}

SNMP::Manager.open(host: HOST) do |manager|
  manager.load_module('UPS-MIB')
  response = manager.get(registers)
  response.each_varbind do |vb|
    if method = TYPE_VALUES[vb.value.ans1_type]
      params_array[vb.name.to_s] = vb.value.send(method)
    else
      puts "Type '#{vb.value.asn1_type}' not recognized!"
      exit(1)
    end
  end
end
pp params_array
```

Comment: Very elegant way to solve the issue, even if I am quite disappointed if it not possible to convert automatically to a type (at least for the common ones: TimeTicks could be converted in a number of ways). 

I am a newbie in Ruby and didn't know it is possible to send methods like this. Thank you for the time you took to answer